# solve error low, but 3D markers very far away from where they should be

Tags: tracking

[image: Screenshot]

So i'm trying to track this [synthetic image sequence](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oen5w1fzu67ngc7/blender_question_syn_track.7z?dl=0) and solve error is very low, but 3D markers are very far from where they should be (both red dots in clip view and those thingies that look like empties in 3D view). What am i doing wrong?

UPDATE: [image: Screenshot2] going to Camera->Sensor fit and switching to horizontal fixes 3D view for a bit, clicking solve make it go to auto and be wrong again; red dots in clip view still wrong

blend files included with [image sequence](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oen5w1fzu67ngc7/blender_question_syn_track.7z?dl=0), as i couldn't figure out how to pack to upload just .blend

Comment: It looks like you have an image in the background of the 3-D view. Here with a normal camera, this will look wrong, even though the markers may be in the right place

Comment: @TheLabCat you mean before solving? i'd expect *that*, but it's after solving

Comment: I mean that the markers May look like they are in the wrong places if projected back onto the footage from 3-D space. Zooming in or out affecting their location is symbolic of this.

Comment: @TheLabCat if projected from random perspective, yeah, but if they're wrong from camera perspective, what was the point of camera tracking?

Comment: If the original footage completely spans the camera view, nothing more nothing less, and the camera is the same depth of field as the original camera, and it still looks wrong, then yes, it is wrong.

Comment: @TheLabCat `Solve camera motion` and `setup tracking scene` almost sets up that stuff to match (footage is cameras background image, not separate object in scene), only it sets `sensor fit` to `auto` instead of `horizontal`, so i'm starting to think that tracking vertical video is bugged

Comment: For vertical videos, setting that `sensor fit` to `horizontal` actually makes it work right.